# Uisng ffmpeg to split video and map chapters in one command

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I'm trying to split a large video into chunks while also mapping the chapters to the chunks. I've already broken the FFMETADATAFILE.txt into multiple parts, but when I run the following command, it neither splits the video nor maps chapters.

```shell
ffmpeg -i "Video.mkv" -ss "00:00:00.000" -t "00:08:14.060" -i "FFMETADATAFILE-pt1.txt" -map_metadata 1 -map_chapters 1 -c:v libx265 -preset veryslow -crf 0 "Video-pt1.mkv"
```

When I run this one, it successfully splits the video:

```shell
ffmpeg -i "Video.mkv" -ss "00:00:00.000" -t "00:08:14.060" -c:v libx265 -preset veryslow -crf 0 "Video-pt1.mkv"
```

And when I run this one, it successfully maps the chapters:

```shell
ffmpeg -i "Video.mkv" -i "FFMETADATAFILE-pt1.txt" -map_metadata 1 -map_chapters 1 -c:v libx265 -preset veryslow -crf 0 "Video-pt1.mkv"
```

But for some reason doing both in one command doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Matt